# How to import JSON file to Excel without coding?

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

Let's say you have a file named `input.json` which contains an array of objects defined in standard JSON format. Something like:

```json
[
    {"name": "notebook", "price": 500.00, "rate": 4.2},
    {"name": "sd-card", "price": 60.49, "rate": 3.5}
]
```

How can I import it as a table in Microsoft Excel without VBA or scripting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have PowerQuery in Excel (I think 2010+) then it's very simple and straightforward. Similar scenarios can be used to cover more complicated cases too. Just follow these steps:

- On the ribbon bar, choose: `Data => Get Data => From File => From Json`
- Select your Json file (input.json in this example)
- In the opened `Power Query Editor` window and on the ribbon bar, choose: `View => Advanced Editor` and input:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("input.json"))
in
    Table.FromList(Source, Record.FieldValues, {"name","price","rate"})
```

or if you want auto-import without specifying column names, use the following block instead:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("input.json"))
in
    Table.FromList(Source, Record.FieldValues)
```

Now on the ribbon bar choose:
`Home => Close & Load`
and you will see a beautiful imported table with all Excel functionality you like.

Comment: Are you going to create a self-answer for all kinds of questions now? Why not start a blog?

Comment: You typically do the conversion before the final statement, so the `in` only contains the finished step, not another action. Look at the JSON example in the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)

Comment: @teylyn I already mentioned you need to use one of those 2 last lines starting with `in` but I changed my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant. There should be a step after `Source` that contains the `Table.FromList()` command. That is then followed by the 'in'. For example `TheTable = Table.FromList(Source, Record.FieldValues)` followed by `in TheTable`. That is the convention.

Comment: This is nice, but you don't get the column names. Without those the value is minimal. [Richard Squire's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684905/6594107) gets you the column names

Answer (score 3):

Another method is using "Table.FromRecords" as this will populate the column headings for you.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\someJsonFileHere.json"))
in
    Table.FromRecords(Source)
```